# Video Embedded in HTML5 won't play in UIWebView

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am loading up a [website](http://kaiopublications.org/content//iLuminateVol1Issue2/index.html) that has a video embedded in the code on the 5th 'page'.  This video plays just fine in the full Safari, but I'm having an issue in my app.  The code for loading it is:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_entry.articleUrl];    
        [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

When I get to the page with the video, it shows up in the frame:
[image]
but when I click on the play button, the app begins messing up.

After clicking on it, the MPMoviePlayerController briefly appears, but instantly gets dismissed and it reloads the original URL, taking the user back to the first page of the issue.  Any thoughts to what may be happening here, or better ways for me to code the app to make sure the video plays in the proper controller?

Comment: Based on your description of the UIWebView reloading the original URL, I have a feeling this is not a problem with the video. What does your `-tick` method do?

Comment: @JohnCromartie The tick method merely shows the UIActivity while the page is loading.  As I said before, the URL runs in Safari just fine.

Comment: I did try your code and it works fine in my simulator, so I'd say that it's something else. Could you show us the code for your `tick` method by any mean?

Comment: @Kirualex it played the video fine in your simulator?  I can't get it to play at all.

Comment: Well that's odd. Even when you remove all but the 2 first lines of your code?

Comment: You need to add what your `tick` function does.

Comment: I figured it out finally.  Later on in code I had `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
    
}`, which was causing it to kill the video playback nearly as soon as it began.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ending up being that when the view disappeared it was setting it to an about:blank page.  So, when the movie controller took over the view to play, it passed that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the format? If not, it's possible it might be a type of file that iOS doesn't play nicely with.

If that's the case, simply drag the mp4 file into iMovie and then click on Share -> Export Movie and select one of the iPhone-compatible formats.

Answer (score 0):

That website contains flash video files which are not supported over iOS.

When you play it on default iOS Safari, webpage is checking its user-agent and automatically shift your page to mobile (iOS) compatible site.

For your application, you require to use that weblink only:

Try this URL instead of current one:
http://kaiopublications.org/content//iLuminateVol1Issue2/html5/index.html

This should work in your app.

Comment: Has this solution helped you or not?

Comment: The issue ended up simply being in the viewDidDisappear method setting an about:blank page.